# Jquery Ajax request post data and stay on that page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two pages first page post the data to second page and I would like to our request remain on second page?

```
$.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    url: base_path + '/second.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        div_contenant: div_contenant
                    },
                    success: function(data){

                    }
                })
```

our second page generates the pdf file, we want that our request remain the second page and show the second page on this call

Comment: I don't get it. Please clarify.

Comment: Is their any parameter/way we can stay on second page rather than returning to first page where request was generated?

Comment: Your question is very unclear but it seems like you are confused about how AJAX works. You seem to be confusing URLs with pages. The JavaScript on your first page POSTs data to the url `/second.php` but does not load the page `/second.php`. So it never leaves the first page. Maybe you really want to get rid of the AJAX call and just load the second page normally.

Comment: @scytale: I want to send my whole page content to second page, so I choose to use ajax for that and our second page is generating the pdf file of that content. So I am trying that our call remain on second page, not return to back.

Comment: there is no return. you never go to the second page. you send data to `/second.php` but you never load that page. Your problem is not that you go "back" to the first page - your problem is that you never leave the first page.

Comment: @scytale: yeah exactly, Is their any way that we leave the first page and send post to second using jquery/js?

Comment: @Aryans: Don't use AJAX, and use a normal HTML `<form>` instead? (you can post the form via JS)

Comment: ok let's step back. a URL is something like `/second.php` or `http://www.google.com` (let's gloss over the details here). A page is not the same as a URL. A page is HTML data that you get from a URL. In this case you are sending data to the URL `second.php` using AJAX POST. What you actually want is to just load the page `second.php`. Don't use AJAX, just load the damn page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use AJAX, just load `/second.php` using a form or link.

Comment: If you need to send POST data, you can make a `<form>`, then submit it with JavaScript.